# Queue system in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

I need to make a Queue table in Mysql, That will be accessed by a Java Application, Jobs in the queue is generated by a Web Application using PHP.

The queue have to work as a First in first out, queue unless a task with height priority is queued.

When a task is completed it will be deleted.

My queue table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `queue` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
    `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_prio_id` (`priority`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Since my Java Application is Multithreaded i need to make the queue select statement is thread safe, so every task is only processed once.

How could the select/update statement look like?

Comment: use a queue-system if you can, if not, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is not a great place to store a Queue. A JMS server like ActiveMQ is designed to do this.

Never the less....

You can do the synchronization in Java by having a lock around access to this table.  Then You need a query to obtain the row for the minimum `id` and another to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column like "process-id".
Then do an `update queue set status = x, pid = pid where status = y LIMIT 1` with pid = processid, x = int for running and y = int for waiting.
Then select this one do your work `select .... where status = y and pid = pid`

Don't forget the case, that your job could die or something, could be usefull to add a time column (like started or something) and clean up every few hours or so